# Retrieving Data From Parent Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-main="1">
        <a href="/controller/action"></a>
        <ul data-submenu="1">
           <li><a href="/controller/action"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Someone clicks on the inner anchor element. How do I retrieve the data-submenu value and the data-main value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were asked to retrieve the values while clicking on the `inner anchor element`, I just given the code accordingly. Actually this complication in selecting that anchor element can be removed by providing an `id` to it.

Reason for using the cache variable(`xFirstLevel`) : In order to reduce the unnecessary `dom traversal`.

Try this out,

```
$("#menu li li > a").click(function(){

    var xFirstLevel = $(this).closest("ul");

    alert(xFirstLevel.data('submenu'));
    alert(xFirstLevel.closest('li').data('main'));

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Upd2/)

Comment: Thank you, That's what I was looking for. Not very familiar with closest(). I'll have to familiarize myself with it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    var submenu = $(this).closest("ul#menu").find("[data-submenu]").data("submenu");
    var main = $(this).closest("ul#menu").find("[data-main]").data("main");
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff -- Haha...ohhh yess

Comment: But, now it's also bound to the outer `<a>` as well.   ;)

Comment: @talemyn OP's question is quite confusing concerning that :(

Comment: Yeah, definitely need some more details to give exactly the right answer.  I took "Someone clicks on the inner anchor element" to mean the lowest level `<a>` in his sample code, but it's definitely a little ambiguous . . .

Comment: I should really look at the code closer, didn't even notice that second `a` on the outer.

Comment: @tymeJV - Yeah, I missed it on my first read through, too.   LOL

Comment: Yep . . . now he just needs to figure out exactly where he wants to bind it.